# Error in counting the rows from the database using php for pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to learn pagination using php and mysql. I have created a function to count the rows in the table to store it and use it in the pagination function but no result occurs and I am unable to understand the problem in the code.

```
function get_row_count() {
    $connect = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows From class";
    $d = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($d);
    if ($c == true) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['rows'];
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('error')</script>";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `$d` != `$result`

Comment: You really need to work on your variable names. As mentioned by aynber you have a typo in your code. If you named your variables properly maybe this wouldn't happen.

Comment: Using `COUNT` will always return one row, so this will never work as expected. What you need to do is return the SELECT query, without COUNT, and use that to derive the number of rows with `mysqli_num_rows()`